# Problems with the color Vector Asset in Floating Action Button

Tags: floating-action-button

So, guys.

I created an Asset Vector to use in my Fluting Action Button(Asset Add or Plus), in white color. When I add it to the FAB, it turns black and I can't change it.

Where can I make the change?

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    app:fabSize="normal"
    app:rippleColor="@color/white"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_confirmar_24"
    />
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rfYjz.png)

Answer (score 0):

Just add *app:tint="@color/white"* in your FloatingActionButton.